# how to check all the CheckBox are checked on button Click in android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-checkbox

Below is the code where I am checking all the mandatory `CheckBox` is checked on NEXT button. There is totally 17 checkbox. But I am showing this in a Alert box so It is not taking this layout in View and taking the count of checked items in actual layout. Please help me to resolve this.

```
public void showConfirmPopup()
{
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SubmitViewActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_uikyc);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    Button back=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_bck);
    Button next=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
    final CheckBox[] checkboxes;
    checkboxes = new CheckBox[17];

    for(int i=0;i < checkboxes.length; i++){
        checkboxes[i] = (CheckBox) findViewById(getIdName("check_" + (i+1)));
    }

    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dialog.cancel();
    }
    });

    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //int lenCheck = checkboxes.length;
    int iCheck = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){

        if(checkboxes[i].isChecked()){
            iCheck++;
        }

    }
    Log.e(String.valueOf(iCheck), "count of checked option");
    if(iCheck != 17){
        Toast.makeText(SubmitViewActivity.this, "Confirm all Checkboxes are checked" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dialog.cancel();
    }else if(iCheck == 17){
    dialog.cancel();
    savedetails = new SaveDetails();
    savedetails.execute();
    }
    }
    });

    dialog.show();

}
```

Comment: What is `checked`? Where are the `checkboxes` defined? Do you have check changed listener? More info will be helpful.

Comment: where is `checked` defined and how are you setting its values

Comment: @AmulyaKhare No I dint use any checked changed Listener. I have just used 17 check box in the layout

Comment: @Manju what is `checked`? Where is it initialized? Where do you `findViewById` for these 17 checkboxes?

Comment: @hiphopdroid it is private boolean checked[];

Comment: @hiphopdroid I think it is wrong now how to get the count of check box

Comment: @AmulyaKhare I can check in IF condition for all the checkbox is it checked or not but instead I must do in any other optimised way

Comment: @Manju sorry I do not understand what you mean. Maybe you should just post the entire code

Comment: @Manju I understand that but maybe the problem is due to HOW you set the values of the array or how you initialize the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Change your `CheckBox` id in xml as **check_1,check_2,check_3...check_17** like below for every 17

```
       <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/check_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="check_1" />
```

and **java**

Declear as `CheckBox[] checkboxs;` in global variable and initilize it like below

```
    checkboxs = new CheckBox[17];

    for (int i = 0; i < checkboxs.length; i++) {
        checkboxs[i] = (CheckBox) findViewById(getIdByName("check_" + (i + 1)));
    }
```

**getIdByName** method

```
public static int getIdByName(final String name) {

     try {

         final Field field = R.id.class.getDeclaredField(name);

         field.setAccessible(true);
         return field.getInt(null);

     } catch (Exception ignore) {
         return -1;
     }
 }
```

and you can check wheather check box is checked or not using below codes.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < checkboxs.length; i++) {

        if(checkboxs[i].isChecked()){
              iCheck++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi it is throwing in  if(checkboxs[i].isChecked()){}

Comment: @Manju what is throwing.

Comment: null pointer exception also cannot resolve the value of checkboxs[i] when I debug

Comment: @Manju Post your full codes i'll edit it and it'll post that.

Comment: @Manju did you add `CheckBox[] checkboxs;` as global variable

Comment: @Manju where is all `CheckBox`? Is it in `activity_uikyc.xml` or somewhere else?

Comment: It is in activity_uikyc.xml only

Comment: @Manju then change it `checkboxes[i] = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(getIdName("check_" + (i+1)));`

Comment: @Manju `dialog.findViewById`